# How to display a boolean status to be active or inactive

Tags: reactjs, jsx

With a request to the backend I reveive the status of a user being true if the user is logged in and false in the other case. But I want to display in a table Active or Inactive, not true of false, like it's happening now:

[image]

And this is the code:

```
const UserRow = ({ data }) =>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>{data.firstName} </td>
    <td>{data.lastName} </td>
    <td>{data.department}</td>
    <td>{data.site}</td>
    <td>{String(data.status)}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>;

UserRow.propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.object
};
```

Right here:

```
<td>{String(data.status)}</td>
```

I display the status. How can I change this into 'Active' or 'Inactive'?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ternary operator

```
<td>{data.status ? 'Active': 'Inactive'}</td>
```

Comment: Great! Thank you!